# Seg Fault:I can't understand why

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I get a pretty weird segmentation fault error when I am trying to use the same function in two different places.

printTVNode function work fine on main.
On Main:

```
printTVNode(headTVNode); /* Works fine here */

TVNodePointer headTopic = NULL;
TopicEmmissions(&headTopic,headTVNode,desiredTopic);
```

When I am trying to use printTVNode inside TopicEmmissions function a get Seg Fault.

```
void TopicEmmissions(TVNodePointer * headTopic,TVNodePointer headTVNode,char * desiredTopic){
    TVNodePointer currentTVNode = headTVNode;
    EmmissionPointer currentEmmission;
    EventPointer currentEvent;
    EventPointer topicSubjects = NULL;
    int flag,countEvent = 1,countEmmission = 1;

    printTVNode(headTVNode); /* Get Segmentation Fault here*/
    ...
```

printTVNode function:

```
void printTVNode(TVNodePointer headTVNode){
    TVNodePointer currentTVNode = headTVNode;

    while ( currentTVNode != NULL ){
        printEmmission(*(currentTVNode->anEmmission));

        currentTVNode = currentTVNode->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you get segmentation fault? in TopicEmission or printTVNode function? Also check the headTVNode being passed to TopicEmissions function

Comment: When I call printTVNode on main function everything is good.But when I am trying to do the same thing inside TopicEmmissions i get seg fault.

Comment: Still think the pointer headTVNode passed to TopicEmissions is bad- see who passes that in and if it is getting deleted before coming in here

Comment: @nikpa Can you give us the definition of the TVNodePointer struct please?

Comment: `*(currentTVNode->anEmmission)` potential `NULL` dereference, hence potential segmentation fault.

Comment: typedef struct TVNode{
 EmmissionPointer anEmmission;
 struct TVNode * next;
} TVNodeType;

typedef struct TVNode * TVNodePointer;

Comment: Could the `headTVNode` point to local memory of a function that was already returned from? That is did you something along these lines: `TVNode nd; return &nd;`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in the following line :

```
printEmmission(*(currentTVNode->anEmmission));
```

In a situation where `anEmmission` is `NULL`, when you try to dereference it, I think you will get a segfault.

Make sure to check that `anEmmission` is not `NULL` before doing dereferencing.

Comment: I call printTVNode on the main function using the same parameter I use for TopicEmmissions and i get the seg fault.Look at the first code block on the question:it's a part of main function.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @nikpa I see that, in that case, is it possible that the problem could be elsewhere in the TopicEmmisions function? If not, is there any operations that are being done before passing the parameters to the printTVNode() function?

Comment: If `anEmmission` is uninitialized, the behavior can be undefined. It may trigger a segfault or print garbage. Add something like `if(currentTVNode->anEmmission!=NULL){printEmmission(...` to check that `anEmmission` does not point to NULL and check if your code initialize `anEmmission` and that `anEmmission` points to something meaningful`.

Comment: @francis Which is what I suggested in my answer. nikpa thinks that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Because I don't want to leak the code here,can anyone give me his/her email?